# http.server - send data to the client

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, instance

Greatings everyone,

I have a main that runs a thread. This thread manages a HTTP server using http.server like this:

```
import binascii, threading
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class Com(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue):      
        MyHandler.queue = queue
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        httpd = HTTPServer(('10.0.0.254', 8000), MyHandler)
        httpd.serve_forever()

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    queue = None    

    def do_POST(self):
        " Receive a POST and put the received frame in the queue "    

    def send(self, toSend):
        self.send_response(200, "OK")
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(toSend)
```

The do_POST method works well, it receive data and send it to the main thanks to the queue.
What I want is: sometimes when I want, the main orders the server to send some data. Normally, the code to send is good. My problem is that I can't, from the main, access to the HTTP server instance to call the send method, because it is managed by http.server.
In Com class (instance in the main), I tried something like:

```
def sendThroughServer(self, toSend):
    MyHandler.send(toSend)
```

Also using class method, but it doesn't seems to work, because it requieres "self".

How can I do that pls ?

Hope it is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I might have misunderstood, but it sounds like you're trying to send data outside of an HTTP request/response cycle. Who would you be sending it to?

Comment: `send()` requires a request context. You can't just send, HTTP is not bidirectional (by design). If you want to push some data from the server to the client (without a request) then you need some other protocol (well, it is somewhat doable over HTTP but really complicated, e.g. long polling). Depending on your context WebSockets might be a good choice.

Comment: Oh my bad. Thanks for your answers. I would like to send it to a single client. The HTTP server can't miss incoming data, so it's a thread. Then in the main, I parse that data and answer when I want (according to an other thread). So, in this configuration, the parsing must be done in the do_POST ? I will check WebSockets, I don't know it.